# How to set metadata for Nestjs Grpc response from an interceptor

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to set metadata for the response to a Grpc request from the Nestjs interceptor.
But I am not able to find where to set it. Does anyone know how this works? This is what I tried so far.

```
Injectable()
export class SomeInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const ctx = context.switchToRpc();
    console.log(ctx.getContext());

    // ctx.getResponse().Metadata.set(key,value)
    return next.handle().pipe(tap((t) => console.log(t)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation within a NATS context. It should be transferrable since they're both `RPCs`.

```js
 export class MetadataInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    if (context.getType() === 'rpc') {
      const message = context.getArgByIndex(0);

      const natsContext = context.switchToRpc().getContext<NatsContext>();

      message.metadata.info = natsContext.getArgs();
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Take note of the `if(context.getType() === 'rpc')` check to ensure it's an rpc operation. You may inject the interceptor by decorating a controller like this: `@UseInterceptors(MetadataInterceptor)`. Or, as a global interceptor in main.ts: `app.useGlobalInterceptors(new MetadataInterceptor());`

Comment: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'info'). Getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I have created a repository to demonstrate how it's done within the gRPC context: https://github.com/alfreddohnani/nestjs-grpc-interceptor. Take note that in the context of NestJS, when working with gRPC, accessing the ServerUnaryCall object directly within an interceptor is not straightforward due to the way NestJS abstracts the gRPC layer. You can only manipulate the metadata in the interceptor. Then, you can access the ServerUnaryCall object in a gRPC controller method and send the metadata as demonstrated in `ProductController`